# What happens if the thread acquires 10 reentrant locks and dies?

Tags: java, reentrantlock

Suppose a thread acquires reentrant lock on a resource multiple times and dies.
What will happen to the resource?
Can another client access the resource?

Comment: Can you show your example code which you used to test this out and clarify to us what is causing the confusion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I asked this doubt. Since re-entrant locks in java maintain holdCount and releases lock once holdCount goes to zero.

Comment: It's easily testable: `public void run() { sharedLock.lock(); return; }`

Answer (score 2):

Proof by demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  final Thread t = new Thread(()->lock.lock());
  t.start();
  t.join();
  System.out.println(t.isAlive());
  System.out.println(lock.tryLock());
}
```

It prints

```
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classical deadlock to me. If the lock is not released by the owner - it will stay locked for ever and for everyone.